# Page flickering on Chrome (mobile version)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I noticed that often when I scroll my bootstrap-page through chrome (mobile version), some parts freeze and other one scroll over and the effect is like image flickering.
I checked on my tablet (samsung galaxy tab 2) and on a friend's galaxy note.
Chrome browser is updated to current version!
For example I can get this effect scrolling down also the bootstrap documentation page like as http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Why does it happen? Did you aware same issue?
Is it a chrome bug? Can I fix it through code?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the flickering by using this at the beginning of CSS

```
*{
  -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
     -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
      -ms-backface-visibility:hidden;
       -o-backface-visibility:hidden;
          backface-visibility:hidden;
}
```